# SQL - Join with keys separated by pipe

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, left-join

TABLE_A

```
 CARGO - HELPERS
 250 - 125|126|5|...(AS MANY AS THEY ARE ASSIGNED ON THE PROGRAM)
```

TABLE_B

```
 ID - NAME
 5 - JAKE
 125 - JOSH
 126 - MEGAN
 9001 - VEGETA
 10 - SPANISH INQUISITION
```

How can I join table A and B to get all those who helped in the cargo?

Will I need to write a function?

I did not develop the program. I'm creating a dashboard and need that info.

Using ORACLE 11g DB

**CONCLUSION --- SOLVED**

After a bit of research and help of friends I was able to get this SQL that worked in my case.

```
SELECT CARGO, HELPERS
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN table_b B ON B.ID IN (SELECT regexp_substr(HELPERS,'[^|]+', 1, level) 
                                 FROM dual 
                                 CONNECT BY regexp_substr(HELPERS,'[^|]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
```

The use of regex to get all until the first `|`, then continue until can't find another pipe. Not the correct explanation but can help you.

Comment: Better question: why is the data in TABLE_A in that format? It violates a principle of table design that is so basic it is called **First** Normal Form. The table should, instead, have multiple rows for each CARGO, with one HELPER per row. (If TABLE_A has other data about each CARGO, then the "helpers" should be in a different **table**, not in the same table where CARGO is primary key.)

Comment: i guess the developer did not wanted to make another table, but i'd say is lazy programming. i'll be questining the development team

Comment: If the development team pushes back, remind them of First Normal Form, and ask them for what reason they are violating it. Do your own little research first, to be able to tell them the many severe disadvantages of using character-separated lists instead of an additional "fact" table.

Comment: this is the only instance so far that i noticed in the DB, its a small table and few clients use, but nonetheless. i'll be contacting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, this is easy:

```
...
from table_a a join table_b b 
               on '|' || a.helpers || '|' like '%|' || b.id || '|%'
...
```

But, as I said in a Comment under your question, the better approach would be to fix your data model (if it's within your power). Your TABLE_A is not in First Normal Form. No wonder you had difficulty writing this (trivial) join; you will feel much more pain for less trivial tasks, not to mention slow execution, no ability to check the validity of "helpers", etc.

Comment: after a bit of research and help of friends i was able to get this sql that worked.
...
SELECT CARGO, HELPERS FROM TABLE_A
inner join table_b B
on B.ID in (select regexp_substr(HELPERS,'[^|]+', 1, level) from dual
   connect by regexp_substr(HELPERS,'[^|]+', 1, level) is not null)
...

Comment: @Hommee - that subquery is what you should use to normalize `TABLE_A`, if you choose to do that. Or, you can save it as a **view**, and in the future use that view as if it was your actual table. (The disadvantage is that the string splitting will have to be done repeatedly, every time you use the view - instead of just once, when you save the data in a table.) For just your query, though, the solution I gave you is probably faster, if speed matters.